# Get data from subarray JSON IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a json array like this:

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 917,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 39
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 918,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 38
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've already get post id, but can't get the post tags id
Need to get data for each post, ex. Post 917 (tag 39), Post 918 (tag 38).

I use the Jsonloader from github, link: github.com/Phillipus/JSONHandler

Comment: Share the code you are using to get the elements of the JSON please.

Comment: Can you add your code here ?

Comment: Its a nested one, just iterate along...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the format for json is wrong. It should be something like:-

```
"posts":[{"id":917,"tags":39},{"id":918,"tags":38}]
```

This is an array of one 2 dictionary objects. Then, you can get the objects using

```
NSArray * postArray = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];
NSDictionary * firstObject = [postArray firstObject];
NSNumber * id1 = [firstObject objectForKey:@"id"];
NSArray * tags1 = [firstObject objectForKey:@"tags"];
NSNumber* tag1 = [[tags firstObject] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Try this out.

**Updated answer:**

```
NSArray * postArray = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];

for(int i=0;i<postArray.count;i++){
 NSDictionary * postObject = [postArray objectAtIndex:i];
 NSNumber * postId = [postObject objectForKey:@"id"];
 NSLog(@"PostID:%@",postId);

 NSArray * postTag = [postObject objectForKey:@"tags"];
   for(int j=0;j<postTag.count;j++){
        NSDictionary * postTagIdDic = [postTag objectAtIndex:j];
        NSNumber * postTagId = [postTagIdDic objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"postTagId:%@",postTagId);
    }
}
```

Comment: format of json is correct, wordpress build json via WP JsonAPI

Comment: hm... then it would be a bit tricky. Let me revise my answer in a while.

Comment: But why there are 4 x { but only 3 x }. Something is not right.

Comment: Just updated the answer to reflect the changes on the json format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    NSError *error=nil;
    id json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"json:%@",json);

            NSArray *a=[[json objectForKey:@"posts"] copy];
            NSArray *tags=[[a objectAtIndex:0] copy];

            NSLog(@"%@",[NSStrig stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tags objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]]);

            [a release];

    }
```